# how does ColumnStore Index can retrieve data if it is not ordered?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, warehouse

i'm learning how to use columnstore in sql server and i can't figure out how it works.
this is  a normale rowstore sample:
[image: rowstore]

If we use columnstore it should look soemthing like this according to [this article](http://searchsqlserver.techtarget.com/tip/xVelocity-Columnstore-Indexes-in-SQL-Server-2012) :
[image: columnstore]

now how is it possible to retrieve ross taylor info if the order is not preserved in the columnstore format?

Comment: consider reading this, as I learnt from here: https://logicalread.com/sql-server-columnstore-index-w02/

Comment: @PrabhatG I have already read it. same issue i don't undestand how jose chincilla info can be retrived if they are not in the same order in the data pages. like jose name is 4th and last name is 1st. how can you link it back.

Comment: Niko Neugebauer has so much in-depth information about column store indexes and you should check out [his blog](http://www.nikoport.com/columnstore/). Your question's answer can be found in [this article](http://www.nikoport.com/2014/10/23/clustered-columnstore-indexes-part-42-materialisation/). It is explained how the materialisation is done, how the data is stored in dictionaries to achieve compression and how to read it back.

Comment: I have read the article you gave @RigertaDemiri . it talks about how to use dictionnaries to use less space for redundant values. but even in his article to materialize the original colum the substitute column used with the dictionnary  has the same order. while in my question the order is not preserved.